# How can I change my touchpad scroll speed in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

Is there a good way to do this? Everything I've found regarding this makes it sound like it's not really possible.

Comment: What does the touchpad scroll speed mean? How do you scroll with touchpad? Two Finger scrolling, edge scrolling? How do you expect it working after the change?

Comment: Many kinds of  touchpads are swing speed sensitive and can accept more touching areas at once, so you can scroll faster just by tilting the fingers more down or up (natural two fingers scrolling example)

Comment: I want to slow down two finger scrolling